# Upload Binary file on aws s3 using java Spring

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am able to upload file Using Form data as given below

[image]

but when i am trying to upload file by selecting binary as input getting error as given below;

```
{"timestamp":1490680735011,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException","message":"Current request is not a multipart request","path":"/uploadBinary"}
```

for that i am writing code as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadBinary", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadBinary(
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] multipartFiles) {
    try {
        System.out.println("starting....");
        fileService.upload(multipartFiles);
        System.out.println("uploaded successfully ");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(new String(
                "Something Went wrong while uploading data to server"),
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(new String("uploaded successfully "),
            HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

this works fine for uploading form data, but for binary selection its not working. how we resolve this issues??

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have added CommonsMultipartResolver in your spring configuration file

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

Comment: I am using annotation baised and added bean to config file also.